# Elementwise Concatenation of vectors in R

Tags: r, vector, concatenation

I have two vectors 
a <- "GT001042-0000100" "GT001049-0000300" "GT001056-0000700"
b <- GTL2 GTNP GTL2

I need output in the form of -
out <- "GT001042-0000100GTL2" "GT001049-0000300GTNP" "GT001056-0000700-GTL2"
How do I do that in R? Someone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste0 should do the job:

```
output = paste0(a,b)
```

Or more general paste if you want to add a seperator between the strings:

```
output = paste(a, b, sep="-")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `str_c` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
output <- str_c(a, b)
```